# Getting checkboxes ticked based on the value extracted from database for edit form

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have my values stored in database as follows:
[image]

I am able to get all the values in my form from database for editing purpose as follows:But I am not able to get checkboxes ticked based on the values that I have stored in my database i.e. if I have MBBS and BDS in my database, i would like to have MBBS and BDS checkboxes ticked in my edit form.
[image]

For single value in course column, i was able to achieve single tick as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for='degree'>Degree : </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="MBBS" id="course" name="course" 
    @if($book->course == "MBBS")
    {{"checked" }}
    @endif
    />MBBS
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" value="BDS" id="course" name="course"
   @if($book->course == "BDS") 
   {{"checked" }}
   @endif
   />BDS
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" value="B.Pharma" id="course" name="course" 
   @if($book->course == "B.Pharma") 
   {{"checked" }}
   @endif/>B.Pharma
  </label>
 </div>
```

How can i access the values in checkboxes of my edit form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your course seem to have comma separated value, so you need to explode it and cross check it.
Try this to get a match

```
@if(in_array("MBBS", explode(",", $book->course)))
    {{"checked" }}
@endif
```